# htaccess redirect from one port to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have want to redirect urls that contains ?_escaped_fragment_= to another port. For an example,

```
http://localhost:8080/web/?_escaped_fragment_=/privacy
```

to

```
http://localhost:8082/web/?_escaped_fragment_=/privacy
```

My current htaccess is as below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.dermveda.com:8082/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

The issue is, if the URL contains `web/`, it doesnt redirect to my new port. But if it doesnt have `web/` it redirects fine.
e.g. 
URLs like `http://localhost:8080/web/?_escaped_fragment_=/privacy`are not redirected. But URLs like `http://localhost:8080/?_escaped_fragment_=/privacy` are redirected. My question is, How should I implement htaccess to redirect URLs with `web/` to another port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is presence of this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
```

This condition means redirect only if your URL is `/`, which means only landing match.

Just remove that condition and have your rule as:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://dev.dermveda.com:8082%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```